# What are good resources for learning to use Illustrator to design iOS apps?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, ios, resource-recommendations

I've been using Photoshop to do visual designs of apps from wireframes until now and it has gone pretty well. But there's a trend these days to do the visuals also in Illustrator use multiple artboards and stuff.

Are there any resources/tutorials/templates for making visual designs for iOS in AI?

Answer (score 0):

This is a good site offering multiple phone templates in .ai format

[Illustrator UX templates](http://uxkits.com/products/mobile-devices-illustrator-template-and-omnigraffle-stencil)

There's also a good selection on speckyboy

[Multiple illustrator templates for mobile design](http://speckyboy.com/2010/09/01/illustrator-template-toolbox-for-web-mobile-and-app-developers/)